# Replacing Sukam fusion 3.5kva Mosfet IRF2807

Tags: mosfet

The mosfets on my Sukam Fusion 3.5kva inverter have blown, I want to replace them.

they have what looks like the following written on them

---

IRF2807

### RP526Y

I can find IRF2807 but not IRF2807 RP526Y, would I need to replace the blown ones with the exact same mosfet?

P.S -This is a home DIY so, I'm not well versed with electronics per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace with any IRF2807, but be sure to check the gate drives of each mosfet bank. Or they might blow again.

First make sure that drive to them is still proper.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how does one check the mosfet gate drive? What should I be looking for?

Comment: You need a rwo channel oscilloscope to see if the signals to mosfet gate are fine and they should not be overlapping. But if you dont have a scopr, at least check the dc voltage level on each mosfet gate, it must be same. And also check the pulldown resistors.

Comment: Thank for pointing me in the right direction, appreciate it, I'm not sure how it's done, am sure google will offer up something :-)